# Add data from additional_information of oauth_client_details to JWT

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

I'm filling in the `oauth_client_details` table from a client registration service. I'm putting some data in JSON format in the `additional_information` field.

```
insert into oauth_client_details(client_id, client_secret, ..., additional_information) values
    ('app-client-id', 'app-client-secret', ..., '{"special-id":"abc-123"}');
```

I would like to store that data in the JWT but cannot see a way to access it. I see it getting loaded and parsed in `JdbcClientDetailsService.loadClientByClientId` and the related `RowMapper` but the data is not there when my token enhancer is called:

```
static class MyTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        // accessToken.additionalInformation is an empty map here!
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

Is there another point in the flow where I can access and inject the value of `special-id` into the JWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could only solve this by adding a custom field to `oauth_client_details`,  load the detail record once again in `TokenEnhancer.enhance()` (Spring loads the record 6 times by this time, so another won't matter), then add the value from my custom field to the JWT as usual.

I could have used the additional_information field to store my custom data, but then I would need to parse the JSON. I see no point in doing that.